# Debug code with in curly braces - c-sharp

Tags: c#, debugging

Typically we use F11 and F10 for debugging in visual studio, but when the code section is within curly braces `{` we may not be able to debug inside lines (refer the attached screen shot lines 36, 37, 38).

How do we debug those sub lines during debugging ?

[image]

Comment: You can add a brekapoint into that function?

Comment: I think you mean "Curly" braces

Comment: That block of code is within a lambda expression which is going to get called back at some point within the AddAuthentication method, if you step over that line then the debugger won't break until the following line of code which will be on line 40. Stick a breakpoint inside the lambda and the debugger will break when that block of code is being run.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Phuzi in a comment. You are pointing to a [lambda statement block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions). This is used to specify some piece of code to be called later from some other code. The common name for this is [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), and functions somewhat similar to the native concept of 'function pointer'.

So when you step thru the code there will only be a single method call that is stepped over in one step. You can add a breakpoint to one of the lines in this lambda statement, and the debugger will break when this line is called. This might happen when you step over the function call, but it might also happen at some later time, or not at all. It all depends on the implementation of `AddAuthentication`.